# Where to put the script to appear under scripts menu in Illustrator cs5.1

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I have a script for Illustrator **CS5.1** that I would like to be part of the scripts menu. I've tried to put it under:

1. C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS5.1\Presets\en_GB\Scripts\
2. C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS5.1\Presets\en_GB\Scripts\myFolder
3. C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS5.1\Presets\
4. C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS5.1\Presets\myFolder

but all of those attempts failed, I have restarted Illustrator, what can be wrong? This is for **Windows 7**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know why, but the solution is to NOT USE `*.jsx` but `*.js` as script extension. When I've changed it to `js` and placed into `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS5.1\Presets\en_GB\Scripts\` it appeared under scripts menu.

With 64bit CS6 Illustrator the path looks like this: `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 (64 Bit)\Presets\en_GB\Scripts`and it accepts `JSX` or `JS` extensions.

Comment: Great. Good to know. in CC and CC 2014 .js and .jsx work

Comment: Thank you. Is there a corresponding location in the user's AppData/Roaming folder (as there is for InDesign)?

Answer (score 13):

And just for good measure, here's

### a Mac solution

(Yes, OP asked for Windows, but many Mac users will find this page too)

[See the elegantly explained answer on Xinrong's blog.](https://xinrongding.wordpress.com/2015/12/21/illustrator-cc-install-scripts-on-mac-os/)

Or if the link ever rots, read the summary below:

### Step 1.

Navigate to

**Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC/Presets/en_GB/Scripts**

and copy the .js or .jsx files there.

The file path may differ depending on your version of Illustrator (could be CS6 instead of CC, for example), and also your language (could be ja_JP instead of en_GB, for example).

### Step 2.

Relaunch Illustrator.

The scripts will then be accessible in Illustrator's menu under **File > Scripts**

Comment: Thank you "Past Mentalist" for anticipating my present needs :)

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a super old question, but since this is the first thing that comes up when I googled it...

The directory is still similar

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC 2018\Presets\en_US\Scripts

Comment: This works perfectly when using Adobe Illustrator CC 2018 in 2020. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

In my localized version of Illustrator CC 2014 it is:

/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC 2014/Presets.localized/de_DE/Skripten

should something similar to for you.

In Illustrator CC (v17) it also is this folder.

```
/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CC/Presets.localized/de_DE/Skripten
```

From the Illustrator CS5 Scripting guide [link](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/illustrator_scripting_guide_cs5.pdf)

Chapter 1 / Page 10

> #### Installing scripts in the Scripts menu
>
> To include a script in the Scripts menu (File > Scripts), save the script in the Scripts folder, located in the  /Illustrator CS5/Presets folder in your Illustrator CS5 installation directory. The script’s filename, minus the file extension, appears in the Scripts menu.

Comment: Points 1 and 2 in my question shows this and both doesnt work, it could be something with CS5.1.